# The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer

Tags: sql-server

I am an having an issue regarding this query

```
SELECT SUM (A.SumTopMarks) FROM (SELECT
            T.section_id,
            SumTopMarks = SUM(S.marks)
        FROM
            dbo.MocktestDetails AS T
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (T.total_section_question)
                    *
                FROM
                    dbo.online_test_marks AS O
                WHERE
                    T.section_id = O.section_id AND t.branch_id = o.branch_id AND t.test_id = o.test_id 
                    AND t.test_id=1 AND o.test_id=1 AND o.student_id=1
                    --AND o.branch_id =@branch_id AND t.branch_id=@branch_id
                ORDER BY
                    O.marks DESC
            ) AS S
        GROUP BY
            T.section_id) AS A
```

I know why it is showing, because of T.total_section_question column, it is declared as nvarchar in my table.

Lets say I wanna run this query,

```
SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM dbo.tblName
```

it's not showing any syntax error , however if rerun like this,

```
DECLARE @n NVARCHAR(3)= '10'

SELECT  TOP (@n) * FROM dbo.adm_BusinessArea
```

its showing an error, how to fix this syntax.
Can I cast this anyway? But casting gives me an syntactical error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @n int= 10

SELECT  TOP (@n) * FROM dbo.adm_BusinessArea
```

Or this in case of varchar data type:

```
DECLARE @n varchar(10) = '10'

SELECT  TOP (cast(@n as int)) * FROM dbo.adm_BusinessArea
```

Here are description and examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Ok sir got your point but what if @n is of type varchar and nvarchar? Then it's showing "The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer."